# Cannot download full Document using HtmlUnit and Jsoup combination (using Java)

Tags: java, jsoup, htmlunit

Problem Statement: 
I want to crawl this page : http://www.hongkonghomes.com/en/property/rent/the_peak/middle_gap_road/10305?page_no=1&rec_per_page=12&order=rental+desc&offset=0

Lets say I want to parse the address, that is "24, Middle Gap Road, The Peak, Hong Kong"

What I did:
I first only tried to load using jsoup, but then I noticed that the page is taking some time to load. So, then I also plugged in HTMLUnit to wait for the page to load first

Code I wrote:

```
public static void parseByHtmlUnit() throws Exception{
        String url = "http://www.hongkonghomes.com/en/property/rent/the_peak/middle_gap_road/10305?page_no=1&rec_per_page=12&order=rental+desc&offset=0";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(30000);
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
        synchronized(page) {
            page.wait(30000);
        }
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(page.asXml());
            String address = ElementsUtil.getTextOrEmpty(doc.select(".addr"));
            System.out.println("address"+address);
        } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Expected output :
In the console, I should get this output:
address 24, Middle Gap Road, The Peak, Hong Kong

Actual output :
address

Comment: As I see, it is a `div` with class `.addr`. This div contains `h2`. Probably, selector should be `.addr > h2`

Comment: See [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50189638/8583692).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
final Document document = Jsoup.parse(
    new URL("http://www.hongkonghomes.com/en/property/rent/the_peak/middle_gap_road/10305?page_no=1&rec_per_page=12&order=rental+desc&offset=0"),
    30000
);
System.out.println(document.select(".addr").text());
```