# Web scraping with jsoup in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to scrape [this website](https://online.singaporepools.com/lottery/en/home) as part of my lesson to learn Kotlin and Web scraping with *jsoup*.

What I am trying to scrape is the `Jackpot $1,000,000 est.` values.

The below code was something that I wrote after searching and checking out a couple of tutorials online, but it won't even give me `$1,000,000` (which was what this code was trying to scrape).

```kotlin
Jsoup.connect("https://online.singaporepools.com/lottery/en/home")
    .get()
    .run {
        select("div.slab__text slab__text--highlight").forEachIndexed { i, element ->
            val titleAnchor = element.select("div")
            val title = titleAnchor.text()
            println("$i. $title")
        }
    }
```

My first thought is that maybe this website is using JavaScript. That's why it was not successful.

How should I be going about scraping it?

Comment: The site can be accessed only from Singapore so I cannot test it myself. Try the following - 1. block JS on your browser and reload it. If you cannot see the value you need - it is JS, so try to use PhantomJS or Selenium. 2. If you do see the value try to send the `userAgent` string of your browser with the `get` request. 3. Open the developer tools and check which HTML files are downloaded to your browser - maybe you are looking at the wrong place.

Comment: User agent filtering is very common (especially for something that is so inefficient)

Comment: @TDG Thanks for this, I tried your method to disable JS content, and indeed the values do not show.. So in that case I'll need to use PhantomJS or Selenium headless browsing to obtain the values right?

Comment: @jakewong Yeah, unless you can either parse the JS easily, or connect directly to where the data is being fetched from

Answer (score 1):

I was able to scrape what you were looking for from [this page](https://www.singaporepools.com.sg/en/product/sr/Pages/toto_results.aspx?sppl=RHJhd051bWJlcj0zNjYx) on that same site.
Even if it's not what you want, the procedure may help someone in the future.

Here is how I did that:

1. First I opened that page
2. Then I opened the [Chrome developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/) by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+
   <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> or
   by right-clicking somewhere on page and selecting *Inspect* or
   by clicking ⋮ ➜ *More tools* ➜ *Developer tools*
3. Next I selected the *Network* tab
4. And finally I refreshed the page with <kbd>F5</kbd> or with the refresh button ⟳

A list of requests start to appear (network log) and after, say, a few seconds, all requests will complete executing. Here, we want to look for and inspect a request that has a *Type* like *[xhr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)*. We can filter requests by clicking the filter icon and then selecting the desired type.

To inspect a request, click on its name (first column from left):

[image: Clicking on a request name]

Clicking on one of the XHR requests, and then selecting the *Response* tab shows that the response contains exactly what we are looking for. And it is HTML, so jsoup can parse it:

[image: Response tab for a request]

Here is that response (if you want to copy or manipulate it):

```html
<div style='vertical-align:top;'>
  <div>
    <div style='float:left; width:120px; font-weight:bold;'>
      Next Jackpot
    </div>
    <span style='color:#EC243D; font-weight:bold'>$8,000,000 est</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div style='float:left; width:120px; font-weight:bold;'>
      Next Draw
    </div>
    <div class='toto-draw-date'>Mon, 15 Nov 2021 , 9.30pm</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

By selecting the *Headers* tab (to the left of the *Response* tab), we see the *Request URL* is `https://www.singaporepools.com.sg/DataFileArchive/Lottery/Output/toto_next_draw_estimate_en.html?v=2021y11m14d21h0m` and the *Request Method* is *GET* and agian the *Content-Type* is *text/html*.

So, with the URL and the HTTP method we found, here is the code to scrape that HTML:

```kotlin
val document = Jsoup
    .connect("https://www.singaporepools.com.sg/DataFileArchive/Lottery/Output/toto_next_draw_estimate_en.html?v=2021y11m14d21h0m")
    .userAgent("Mozilla")
    .get()

val targetElement = document
    .body()
    .children()
    .single()

val phrase = targetElement.child(0).text()
val prize = targetElement.select("span").text().removeSuffix(" est")

println(phrase) // Next Jackpot $8,000,000 est
println(prize)  // $8,000,000
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution for parsing a dynamic page with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/overview/) and jsoup.
We first get and store the page with Selenium and then parse it with jsoup.

Just make sure to download the [browser driver](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/getting_started/installing_browser_drivers/#quick-reference) and move its executable file to your classpath.
I downloaded the [Chrome driver version 95](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) and placed it along my Kotlin *.kts* script.

```kotlin
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe")
val result = File("output.html")
// OR FirefoxDriver(); download its driver and set the appropriate system property above
val driver = ChromeDriver()
driver.get ("https://www.singaporepools.com.sg/en/product/sr/Pages/toto_results.aspx")
result.writeText(driver.pageSource)
driver.close()

val document = Jsoup.parse(result, "UTF-8")
val targetElement = document
    .body()
    .children()
    .select(":containsOwn(Next Jackpot)")
    .single()
    .parent()!!

val phrase = targetElement.text()
val prize = targetElement.select("span").text().removeSuffix(" est")

println(phrase) // Next Jackpot $8,000,000 est
println(prize)  // $8,000,000
```

Another version of code for getting the target element:

```kotlin
val targetElement = document
    .body()
    .selectFirst(":containsOwn(Next Jackpot)")
    ?.parent()!!
```

I only used the following dependencies:

- *org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.0.0*
- *org.jsoup:jsoup:1.14.3*

See the [standalone script file](https://gist.github.com/mahozad/a55245b84ae86294f5481ae7b9df6839). It can be [executed with Kotlin runner from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67393230/8583692) like this:

```sh
kotlin my-script.main.kts
```